# MySQL TABLE - Showing no info at all

Tags: mysql

[image]

In this database I have 3 tables. Today all this tables worked perfectly but suddenly the table "sistema" stopped showing its content here in PhpMyAdmin and on the php coding also. The other 2 tables are working perfectly. This table "sistema" is the only one having this problem. I googled and: Repair table PhpMyAdmin Option didn't work at all. What could be causing this problem and How can I fix it. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to export the table then import again

Comment: I tried but all tables, when i try to export: throw this error: Some errors have been detected on the server! Please look at the bottom of this window.

Comment: Maybe some corrupted file occurs, re install or use xampp backup files

Comment: I just clicked the "ignore" button for this error and then I could export the table successfully. Then i imported in on another database, but all data i had on the table is gone, seems to be that i lost all content of the table :(. Is there any way to auto backup periodically XAMPP MYSQL's tables ?

Comment: A batch file can do,

Comment: you can write simple batch file and enable a scheduler to run periodically.
Open a Windows command line.

**Specify the directory to mysqldump utility**

Create a dump of your MySQL database.

`mysqldump.exe --user=YourUserName --password=YourPassword --host=localhost --port=3306 --result-file="Pathdump.sql" --databases "DatabaseName"`